# Having text change with the background to a new color, like a Parallex background

Tags: css, sass, scroll

I'm working on a web application with a fixed header.
The header has a green background and white text. What I want it to do is parallax change into a white background with black text as the user scrolls down.

I can get the background to do this, by for example using two overlaying divs with different backgrounds (one green and one white) and z-indexes, one at the top positioned normally and the other fixed. Example code:

```
.white-bg {
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.green-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu-bar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

But I can't get the text to simultanously change from white to black, clearly I cant make it transparent or use the same technique as the backgrounds.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I will check for the scroll event and change the header class:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        header.classList.add("active");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
```

POC:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size: 48px;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: green;
            margin: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        body {
            background: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 onclick="doIt()">Hello World</h1>
</body>

<script>

    function doIt() {
        let i = 0;
        const x = setInterval(() => {
            document.querySelector("h1").style = `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, white, green ${i}%);
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`;
            i += 10;
            if (i > 2000) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.querySelector("h1").style = 'color: white;';
            }
        }, 15);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: This will make the text color change instantly, not a parallax effect

Comment: add `transition: 0.5s`

Comment: that will make it gradual, but not parallex. The text has to change relative to the user scrolling, so being partially both colors in the transition, not on a timer